# Sandbox Clear Purchase History isn't really clearing the history, how to get the INITIAL_BUY event again?

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

[image]
[image: screenshot of Clear Purchase History popup]

I clear the Purchase History for my Apple App Store Sandbox User, but when I try to subscribe with that user again, Apple SHOULD be sending me a notification/event where the type/subtype is `SUBSCRIBED / INITIAL_BUY` so that I can test the process from the beginning (which is what Clearing Purchase History is supposed to be for). However, the event that Apple is sending to my server is `SUBSCRIBED / RESUBSCRIBE`.

I need to be able to generate events starting from `SUBSCRIBED / INITIAL_BUY` so that I can test my server code is updating user accounts appropriately, etc.

Am I missing something in clearing the purchase history? Do I need to do something else to make sure this user is completely cleared so I can get that `INITIAL_BUY` event?

Comment: Happening to me as well, may be a regression on Apple's part. I ended up just creating new Sandbox accounts to test subsequent purchases